# C# пробелы после значения в таблице после загрузки из локальной базы данных

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

В Visual Studio 2015 сгенерировал локальную базу данных, добавил datagrid и привязал его к bindingSource. Все данных сохраняются и загружаются, но после загрузки добавляются пробелы к тексту. К примеру:
в поле nchar(10) "hhhh__________".Там где "_" это пробелы.
Спасибо

Comment: может стоило сделать колонку `nvarchar(10)` ? `nchar`-- вроде фиксированной длины

Comment: Потому что `char` и `nchar` всегда имеют фиксированную длину, дополняясь пробелами при необходимости. Используйте `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

для nvarchar память выделяться во время заполнения строки символами, для vchar - она уже выделена размерностью.

```
nchar [ ( n ) ]
```

Строковые данные постоянной длины в Юникоде. Параметр n определяет длину строки и должен иметь значение от 1 до 4000. Размер при хранении составляет удвоенное значение n в байтах. Если кодовая страница параметров сортировки использует двухбайтовые символы, размер хранения остается равным n байт. В зависимости от символьной строки для хранения n символов может понадобиться менее n байт. По стандарту ISO синонимами для nchar являются national char и national character..

```
nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]
```

Строковые данные переменной длины в Юникоде. Параметр n определяет длину строки и должен иметь значение от 1 до 4000. Значение max указывает, что максимальный размер при хранении составляет 2^31-1 байт (2 ГБ). Размер хранилища в байтах вдвое больше числа введенных символов + 2 байта. По стандарту ISO синонимами для типа nvarchar являются типы national char varying и national character varying.